# Throw : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'

Tags: powershell, uipath

I want to create a connection to **remote desktop** connection using **UIPath**. The connection is done using **PowerShell**.

It logs in to the remote server, but at the end, the **UIPath** gives me this error.

Can someone help me solve it?

It is linked to the input field.

The input of the PowerShell Activity:

```
  cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/192.1.... /user:admin /pass:passs....
    mstsc /v:192.1.....
```

Comment: I'd need more info to help you, but I might be able to help your post get more attention. Can you relay the specific steps (1, 2, 3) your executing. Note at what step you get an exception and copy the full exception into the post. Also, if you're adding commands, use the code button at the top to format it in lieu of wrapping in double-quotes. I can't speak for anyone else, but I never know if the double quotes are part of the command or just formatting.

Comment: @Adam If a command determines the quotes aren't needed, the interpreter will strip them in the background (both cmd and powershell). (although disregard what I said as I see now it's in the context of the post's editing)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  but still useful information :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have not posted your code, so here is what I used when I did it a while ago.

```
#Add Credential
cmdkey /generic:server01.contoso.com /user:contoso\userid /pass:Secretpassword

#run mstsc
mstsc -v server01.contoso.com
```